# ¿Cómo colocar una imagen al lado derecho de un grupo de cartas?

Tags: html

En este código trato de poner una lista de cards que sean responsive (cuando la resolución sea md o superior muestre 3 cartas, cuando sea sm muestre 2), al lado de estas cartas tengo que poner un "espacio publicitario" pero no logro hacer que queden a la derecha de las cartas. No entiendo muy bien si es un problema de anidación de rows o es que algún atributo funciona diferente a como yo esperaba.

```
<div class="container">
        <h1>Portal de películas</h1><hr>
        <div class="row col-md-8 col-sm-10 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-sm-2">
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="Imágenes/avengers.jpg" alt="AvengersEndgame">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Avengers: Endgame</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Abril 22, 2019</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <small class="text-muted">Actualizado hace 3 minutos</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="Imágenes/elcamino.jpg" alt="ElCamino">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">El Camino: A Breaking Bad Movie</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Octubre 11, 2019</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <small class="text-muted">Actualizado hace 3 minutos</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="Imágenes/godzillakong.jpg" alt="GodzillaKong">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Godzilla VS Kong</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Marzo 25, 2021</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <small class="text-muted">Actualizado hace 3 minutos</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="Imágenes/joker.jpg" alt="Joker">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Joker</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Octubre 2, 2019</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <small class="text-muted">Actualizado hace 3 minutos</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2 row-cols-md-1">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="Imágenes/publicidad1.jpg" alt="Publicidad1">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="Imágenes/publicidad2.jpg" alt="Publicidad2">
        </div>
```

Comment: ¿Que versión de Bootstrap estás usando?

Comment: 5 beta 3 (latest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te falta un `div` `.row` para contener los dos `md-8` y `md-4`

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Portal de películas</h1><hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row col-md-8 col-sm-10 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-sm-2">
      <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="Imágenes/avengers.jpg" alt="AvengersEndgame">
          <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Avengers: Endgame</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Abril 22, 2019</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
              <small class="text-muted">Actualizado hace 3 minutos</small>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="Imágenes/elcamino.jpg" alt="ElCamino">
          <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">El Camino: A Breaking Bad Movie</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Octubre 11, 2019</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
              <small class="text-muted">Actualizado hace 3 minutos</small>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="Imágenes/godzillakong.jpg" alt="GodzillaKong">
          <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Godzilla VS Kong</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Marzo 25, 2021</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
              <small class="text-muted">Actualizado hace 3 minutos</small>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="Imágenes/joker.jpg" alt="Joker">
          <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Joker</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Octubre 2, 2019</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
              <small class="text-muted">Actualizado hace 3 minutos</small>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2 row-cols-md-1">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="Imágenes/publicidad1.jpg" alt="Publicidad1">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="Imágenes/publicidad2.jpg" alt="Publicidad2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, suerte!

Comment: El resultado funciona, pero cuando lo aplico a mi código original sigue el problema, ¿Será que el problema radica en cómo esta codificado antes? Tengo una barra de navegación al principio en donde está indicado el `div=class "container"`.

Comment: fíjate que yo le agregue el cierre de `</div>` del `container` puede ser que integraste todo mi código y ese `</div>` de cierre de mas rompa tu codificación

Answer (score 0):

¿Algo así? Solo especifiqué que estuviese a la derecha y agregué un `card columns` igual usando la beta 3 de Bootstrap 5, espero te sirva.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <h1>Portal de películas</h1>
         <hr>
         <!--AGREGAMOS EL FLOAT-END PARA ESPECIFICARLE QUE LO QUEREMOS A LA DERECHA-->
         <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2 row-cols-md-1 float-end">
            <!--AGREGUÉ EL CARD COLUMNS, DE ESTA FORMA MANTENEMOS EN UNA COLUMNA AMBOS ANUNCIOS-->
            <div class="card columns">
               <div class="card">
                  <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/standard/nature/111.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Publicidad1">
               </div>
               <div class="card">
                  <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/standard/nature/111.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Publicidad2">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row col-md-8 col-sm-10 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-sm-2">
            <div class="card">
               <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/standard/nature/111.jpg" alt="AvengersEndgame">
               <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Avengers: Endgame</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Abril 22, 2019</p>
               </div>
               <div class="card-footer">
                  <small class="text-muted">Actualizado hace 3 minutos</small>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
               <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/standard/nature/111.jpg" alt="ElCamino">
               <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">El Camino: A Breaking Bad Movie</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Octubre 11, 2019</p>
               </div>
               <div class="card-footer">
                  <small class="text-muted">Actualizado hace 3 minutos</small>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
               <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/standard/nature/111.jpg" alt="GodzillaKong">
               <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Godzilla VS Kong</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Marzo 25, 2021</p>
               </div>
               <div class="card-footer">
                  <small class="text-muted">Actualizado hace 3 minutos</small>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
               <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/standard/nature/111.jpg" alt="Joker">
               <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Joker</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Octubre 2, 2019</p>
               </div>
               <div class="card-footer">
                  <small class="text-muted">Actualizado hace 3 minutos</small>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```